# Why does this resistor avoid this oscillation?

Tags: coil, oscillation

I am learning the effects of diodes going trough ON to OFF (so that I can see the consumption of these kind of power supplies) and, when it comes to simulate the circuit, I dont understand why if I remove the resistor shown at the image, all the circuit gets unstable.

Here is the image of both simulations:

The first one, without resistor. The Voltage and Intensisty oscillates.

At the second one, after adding that resistor, the oscillation disappears

[image]

Thanks for helping :) . I still dont know how can I analyse the effect of that resistor (Logic, basis of circuit, Laplace... ) as I am not used to work with coils.

Comment: we know nothing of your simulation settings - is there already the steady state found? Has L1 some assumed capacitance? Is it possible for us to get some explanation of the functional (=practical )idea of this circuit? Why is 800 watts taken half time from the 200V source to the current source and then 4A heats the diode.

Comment: If there i the steady state  at the beginning of the simulation output and there's some capacitance in the coil, the simulation results seem right. But that does not reveal any functional idea for the circuit.

Comment: You'll find a series R with inductor dampenes oscillation as well. Adding a cap in parallel to diode will lower the osc freq